# Jquery Multiple Selector Call to a Fade-in-fade-out function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

maybe it has been solved somewhere on this website but I did not find the answer. Maybe this is because I am pretty new to jQuery and don't really know what may cause the problem.

So I have this code that I add on my Wordpress Website. I found the original code on this website and I tried to adjust it to my need.

```
(function(){

    var j = 0;
    var delay = 2200; //millisecond delay between cycles

    jQuery.fn.rotateImg = function() {
        var list = jQuery(this);
        function cycleThru() {
            var jmax = list.length -1;
            jQuery(list.selector + ":eq(" + j + ")")
                .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,800)
                .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 800, function(){
                    (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                        cycleThru();
                });
        }
        cycleThru();

    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".test ul li, ul.logos li").rotateImg();
    });

})();
```

It works fine when I am only calling it with one selector but when I add a second one the opacity change one multiple lists item at the same time (I think it's half on the list item). My first unordered list has only two list item so I guess the bug has to do with it.

I am sorry for my bad english by the way and thank you for your help.

Oh... and I am using jQuery version 1.7.2

**Edit : I have been able to replicate my bug. You can see it here :** http://jsfiddle.net/selbh/5kDZn/18/

Comment: All of the animations are queued in the same queue. It seems that each selected set of elements should have their own queues.

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem. I do not know how to fix this but at least now I know what to search. Thank you and I am going to give you feedback when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW VERSION**

http://jsfiddle.net/selbh/5kDZn/18/

```
(function($){

    var j = 0;
    var delay = 500; //millisecond delay between cycles


    $.fn.rotateImg = function() {

        $(this).each(function () {

            var list = $(this).find('li');
            function cycleThru() {
                var jmax = list.length -1;
                list.eq(j)
                    .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,800)
                    .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                    .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 800, function(){
                        (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                            cycleThru();
                    });               
            }
            cycleThru();

        });



    };

    $(function() {
        $(".test ul, ul.logos").rotateImg();
    });


})(jQuery);​
```

**OLD VERSION:**

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/selbh/5kDZn/17/

```
(function($){

    var j = 0;
    var delay = 500; //millisecond delay between cycles


    $.fn.rotateImg = function() {

        var list = $(this);
        function cycleThru() {
            var jmax = list.length -1;
            list.eq(j)
                .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,800)
                .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 800, function(){
                    (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                        cycleThru();
                });               
        }
        cycleThru();

    };

    $(function () {
        $(".test ul li, ul.logos li").rotateImg();
    });



})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: It does not work sorry. With your function it animates the first list then the second one but I want them to animate at the same time.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else in my Wordpress because it is still doing the same thing. Animating the first unordered list then the second one.

Comment: Ok so I have been able to replicate my bug. You can see it on this link : http://jsfiddle.net/selbh/5kDZn/18/

Comment: I don't see any bug here. How do you want it to work? What should it do?

Comment: Thats OK I just split in two functions